# How can I create a modular form without repeating coding?

Tags: php, html, forms, module, frame

Im sorry I know this is probably too vague but my knowledge is too limited.  So I can't formulate a good Google question.

I have successfully created a form with parts A-E using HTML - PHP(server).  I want to make additional forms with a variable  part A but keeping parts B-E the same.  I don't want to have the parts on separate web pages because the 1) the user needs to be able to do this quickly and B) there is too much info and you would get lost if you couldnt refer back to what you put in.

Is it possible to create separate documents for A, B, C, D, and E and then have master page pull together the different files to make a single page.  When you would click submit the server side page would use the variables from all the different parts.

Could this be done with frames and the  coding?

Having parts B-E as separate files would allow me to quickly change something in part B for all forms rather than going into each form over and over again to make the coding change.

Sorry for the long post.  Thanks!

Comment: You can use classes, you might want to look over [this](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just include separate files inside a main form:

In `main-form.php`:

```
<?php require 'process.php'; ?>

<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <?php include 'parts/A.php'; ?>
  <?php if (something) include 'parts/B.php'; ?>
  ...
</form>
```

In `process.php` you'd have the logic of $_POST variables. So you'd have folder structure like this:

```
form
-- main-form.php
-- process.php
-- parts
   -- A.php
   -- B.php
   -- ...
```